# Reflection: get Static method from the parent class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have task to get static method using reflection like this :

```
myType.GetMethod("MyMethod",BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);
```

In case if class contains `MyMethod` all works correctly, but in case if parent class contains `MyMethod` I receive null :(. How can I call static method from the parent using reflection like code that I describe above? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` binding attribute. (I haven't tried it myself, so my apologies if I waste your time.)

Answer (score 0):

very simple get the type object that describes the parent class and execute the above code on that object that will give you the MethodInfo object you need. Invoke the methodInfo object passing it an object of myType for the instance parameter